# chef-client is not running while bootstraping from workstration or on a node

Tags: chef-infra

I have installed chef server package on linux server and also have one linux workstation and a linux node on AMAZON EC2.I am trying to run the following bootstrap command on workstation:

```
chef exec knife bootstrap 10.0.xx.xx -x ec2-user --sudo -i keyfile.pem --node-name Chef_Test_Node
```

But chef-client is not working on node. Getting below error:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Network Error:

There was a network error connecting to the Chef Server: Error connecting to https://xx.xx.xx.xx/organizations/xxx/clients - getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Relevant Config Settings:

chef_server_url "https://xx.xx.xx.xx/organizations/xxx"

If your chef_server_url is correct, your network could be down.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am able to run knife client list or node list which proves that there is no issue with network from my workstation

Could you please let me know how can i resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: The node that you are bootstrapping cannot reach https://xx.xx.xx.xx

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply.. but what could be possible reason for this issue as i have opened all required ports i.e. http and https both are opened from server, workstation and from node.

Comment: Log into the target node and try `curl https://xx.xx.xx.xx`.

Comment: Do you have to go through a proxy server in order to connect to the remote server?  Many company networks require that, in which case you can set environment variables of http_proxy and https_proxy to allow chef to go through your proxy server as well.

Comment: Many thanks for reply...yes this might be the issue as i am using a NAT server for internet access..please let me  know where i need to set http_proxy and https_proxy settings to allow chef??

Comment: i have added following in knife.rb file:

https_proxy        'https://ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:443'
https_proxy_user   'xxxx'
https_proxy_pass   'xxxx'

But still getting same below mentioned issue and now no knife command is working.

ERROR: Network Error: Error connecting to https://ip-xx-xx-xx-xx/organizations/xx/users - getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Check your knife configuration and network settings

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can anyone plz give me some hint on this issue??

Comment: I have tested on target node: curl -k https://server/organizations/organization_name, but below error is coming:
 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ip-10-xx-xx-xx

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I was running CHEF on a local LAN with out the benefit of a proper DNS service running, therefore I had to rely on the /etc/hosts file for the host name resolution. On the new node I added, I had forgotten to seed the /etc/hosts file with the entries that corresponded to each server in my Chef cluster so it couldn't resolve the "chef-server" name.

The FIX:
Once I put the proper entries in the /etc/hosts file, everything ran like it should have.

```
    /etc/hosts:

127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.1.165   chef-admin
192.168.1.160   chef-server
192.168.1.161   chef-node1
192.168.1.162   chef-node2
192.168.1.163   chef-node3
192.168.1.164   chef-node4
```

Comment: THANK YOU! /etc/hosts was set on the chef-server, and my workstation/dev environment. Didn't think to add it to my Node-Test server.

Answer (score 0):

The proxy settings are set in the [/etc/client.rb file](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client.html) on the client node (which of course you'll only have post bootstrap).

I don't think you want that. If you in fact have a NAT, HTTP proxy settings won't do you any good. Also you would still have to solve the chicken and egg bootstrap problem.

If you *do* in fact have an https proxy you could:

- temporarily attach an elastic IP to your instance and bootstrap.
  (NOTE use a security group to only allow incoming on port 22 from
  your chef server)
- Once you bootstrap you can remove the elastic IP
  and update the client.rb to point to your https proxy.

(NOTE also that amazon will charge you for having unattached elastic IPs)

If you do not have an http proxy but do in fact have a NAT you should do the following:

- 1) Confirm workstation can execute knife commands on server (something like: knife user list )
- 2) confirm server can ssh to client (if you have a nat you'd need an incoming forwarding rule to make this happen)
- 3) confirm client can connect via https to server

Test with: curl -k https://server/organizations/organization_name

Once you know which connection is failing you can start to uncover the reason why.

Comment: As i am using NAT server, please find below my answer:

1) Confirm workstation can execute knife commands on server (something like: knife user list )
Ans: Yes, i am able to execute each knife commands on workstation and after executing curl -k https://server/organizations/organization_name, it is giving me below output:
 
 <html><body>You are being <a href="https://ip-10-xx-xx-xx:443/signup">redirected</a>.</body></html>

Comment: 2) confirm server can ssh to client
Ans: Yes, after executing "chef exec knife bootstrap 10.xx.xx.xx -x ec2-user --sudo -i key.pem --node-name Chef_Test_Node" , it is able to ssh to client and giving below output:

 Connecting to 10.xx.xx.xx
 10.xx.xx.xx Starting first Chef Client run...
 10.xx.xx.xx Starting Chef Client, version 12.2.1
 10.xx.xx.xx Creating a new client identity for Chef_Test_Node using the validator key.
 10.xx.xx.xx [2015-05-05T08:10:00+00:00] ERROR: Error connecting to https://ip-10-xx-xx-xx/organizations/organization_name/clients, retry 1/5

Comment: 3) confirm client can connect via https to server
Ans: I have tested with: curl -k https://server/organizations/organization_name, but below error is coming:
 curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ip-10-xx-xx-xx

Please help me to resolve this issue.